# What is the smallest positive integer such that 1-2+3-4+5-6+...+(-1)^(n+1)n is more than or equal to 100?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, problem-solving, integers

My attempt to answer this question was to split the sum of this sequence into the sum of other two sequences i.e. 1,3,5... and -2,-4,-6... which ended up giving me the wrong answer to the problem. I do not understand how this sequence ends up being the sum of 1,-1,2,-2, and so on. Could someone please explain how this sequence is the same as the sequence I just mentioned, and why splitting it into two sequences is wrong?

Comment: $$\begin{align}
1&=1\\
1-2&=-1\\
1-2+3&=2\\
1-2+3-4&=-2\\
\cdots\end{align}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint : $$-2+3=-4+5=-6+7=\cdots=1$$

Comment: $199{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

$1+(-2+3)+(-4+5)+(-6+7)+\dots= 1+1+1+1+\dots=100$. $100$ ones required. Last $99$ ones comes from two terms. Therefore number of terms required is $99\times2+1= 199$.

Answer (score 0):

For even $n$ it's negative.

But for odd $n$ we obtain:
$$-1-1-...-1+n\geq100$$ or
$$-\frac{n-1}{2}+n\geq100$$ or $$n\geq199.$$